# How to set environment variable for saltstack with cherrypy api

Tags: cherrypy, salt-stack

I have a task to run shells with salt cherrypy api, now want to add some environment variable, look for docs but no idea.

My salt api url: `http://<Salt Master IP>:8000`
This is my request body:

```
{
    'client': 'local', 
    'fun': 'cmd.script', 
    'kwarg': {
        'env': {
            'MYENV': 'My Value'
        }
    }, 
    'expr_form': 'list', 
    'tgt': '<salt node address>', 
    'arg': ['http://<shell download url>']
}
```

> about: [rest cherrypy document](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.html)